# jquery animated slide show not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following code for an image slider. It is a bit complicated because i want to use the slider code for multiple slider elements on the page. See below the code for one slider:
The problem i am having is described at the bottom.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.vertical_img').first().addClass('display currentvertical_img').removeClass('invisable');
 $('.horizontal_img').first().addClass('display currenthorizontal_img').removeClass('invisable');
 $('.diagonal_img').first().addClass('display currentdiagonal_img').removeClass('invisable');
 
 // image slider interaction with user
 $('.right').click(function(){
  next($(this).data('id'));
 });
 $('.left').click(function(){
  previous($(this).data('id'));
 });
});


function next(img_class){
 var count;
 $('.current'+img_class).animate({left: 0}, 500, function(){
  console.log("animated?");
  $('.current'+img_class).removeClass('display current'+img_class).addClass('invisable previous'+img_class);

  if($('.previous'+img_class).is(':last-child')) {
   count = $('.'+img_class).first().data('num');
   $('.'+img_class).first().removeClass('invisable').addClass('display current'+img_class);
  }
  else{
   $('.previous'+img_class).next().addClass('display current'+img_class).removeClass('invisable');
   count = $('.previous'+img_class).next().data('num');
  }
  $('.'+img_class+'_slider').text(count+'/4');
  $('.previous'+img_class).removeClass('previous'+img_class);
 });
}

function previous(img_class){
 var count;

 $('.current'+img_class).removeClass('display current'+img_class).addClass('invisable previous'+img_class).animate({right: 0});
 if ( $('.previous'+img_class).is(':first-child')) {
  count = $('.'+img_class).last().data('num');
  $('.'+img_class).last().removeClass('invisable').addClass('display current'+img_class);
 }
 else{
  $('.previous'+img_class).prev().addClass('display current'+img_class).removeClass('invisable');
  count = $('.previous'+img_class).prev().data('num');
 }
 $('.'+img_class+'_slider').text(count+'/4');
 $('.previous'+img_class).removeClass('previous'+img_class);
}
```

```css
.main_image_slide_container{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px;
    right:50px;
  width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
 }

 .image_slide_container_all_text_wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: overlay;
 }

 .image_slider_title{
  float: left;
 }

 .image_slider_counter{
  float: right;
 }

 .main_image_slide_container .image_slider_counter{
  display: none;
 }

 .image_slide_container_all_text_wrapper .image_slider_counter{
  display: block;
 }

 .slider_images_wrapper_window{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
 }

 .image_slider_controls{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 .left{
  left: 0;
  cursor: default;
 }

 .left:hover{
  cursor: url(../../data/cursor_left.png) 40 30, move;
 }

 .right{
  right: 0;
  cursor: default;
 }

 .right:hover{
  cursor: url(../../data/cursor_right.png) 40 30, move;
 }

 .slider_images_container{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

 .slider_images_container img{
        position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_image_slide_container">
     <div class="image_slide_container_all_text_wrapper">
      <div class="image_slider_title big_text font">Gravient Vertical</div>
      <div class="image_slider_counter big_text font vertical_img_slider">1/4</div>
     </div>
     <div class="slider_images_wrapper_window">
      <div class="image_slider_controls left" data-id="vertical_img"></div>
      <div class="image_slider_controls right" data-id="vertical_img"></div>
      <div class="slider_images_container">
       <img class="vertical_img invisable" data-num="1" src="https://www.geeky-gadgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/google-mac-linux1.jpg">
       <img class="vertical_img invisable" data-num="2" src="https://images.techhive.com/images/idge/imported/article/ctw/2012/10/19/samsung_chromebook_338-100391696-orig.jpg">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="image_slider_counter big_text font vertical_img_slider">1/4</div> <!--mobile counter -->
    </div>
```

So my current problem is that the images are not animating to the left. And i dont know why.. I am pretty sure my animate syntax is correct. I copy pasted it from the jquery website.

All suggestions and tips are welcome. 
If something is not clear please let me know so i can clarify it!

Comment: you are changing left/top property of static element

Comment: what exactly do you mean? this is wrong? should i make it dynamic? how would i make it dynamic?

Comment: they should be positionned, using absolute/relative or fixed positon ... by default an element has a static position so you can move it with left/top/right/bottom

Comment: i tried with relative position, but it didnt work. I will update the question so you can see it.

Comment: just to be sure the images should be positioned relative right? that is what i did now in the code see the question.

Comment: can you create codepen or more complete code ? it seems there is a lot of missing things, i don't see the logic of aniamting the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164243/discussion-between-futurecake-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `invisable css`. Here is the working Example.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akky123/6ah3r2bv/)